# MySQL Show all months

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with creating a query that will show the name of the month even if there is no activity for that month.

I'm only getting my data from one table.

```
| apptID |   apptType      |     Date    |
|----------------------------------------|
| 1      | Implementation  | 2017-03-19  |
| 2      | Meeting         | 2017-03-01  |
| 3      | Meeting         | 2017-04-04  |
```

etc...

I was able to create a query that shows the total number of appointments (per type, per month), however it doesn't show the months that has no activity.

This is my code:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(appointment.date, '%M') AS 'Month',
SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Meeting' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Meeting',
SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Consultation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Consultation',
SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Implementation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Implementation',
SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Follow-up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Follow-up'
FROM appointment GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OidO.png)

I wanted to keep this same format (records are by month)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can list the months in a subquery in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT m.mon,
       SUM(a.description = 'Meeting') AS Meeting,
       SUM(a.description = 'Consultation') AS Consultation,
       SUM(a.description = 'Implementation') AS Implementation,
       SUM(a.description = 'Follow-up' ) AS Followup
FROM (SELECT 1 as mon UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4
     ) m LEFT JOIN
     appointment a
     ON MONTH(a.date) = m.mon
GROUP BY m.mon;
```

Notes:

- This uses a short-hand for counting values.  MySQL treats a boolean expression as 1 for true and 0 for false.
- Don't put single quotes around column aliases.  They should only be used for string and date constants.
- When you are working with months, you should really take the year into account (although I did not make that change to the query).
- You can add more months to the subquery, as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a second table that has only the months in it, and then `left join` against that. Sorry that the answer isn't more detailed - writing this on a mobile device, which is a pain...

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i can't create a table with just the month information and do a left join.

i did saw a solution here (https://www.daniweb.com/programming/databases/threads/334766/select-query-to-results-all-12-months-even-if-data-not-exist), but I don't know how to integrate it with the other four columns that I want to create.

Thank you though